# How does soundcloud web make an android notification

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-notifications, soundcloud

I am talking about this notification:

[image]

Somehow SoundCloud (the website) makes this notification appear and it has working controls. I do not have the app installed, that notification originates from `com.android.chrome`. I don't really *need* to know this to reproduce it, but I'm curious as to how it accomplishes this and perhaps in what other ways you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accomplished with Chrome Media Notifications. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/media-notifications

To get the playback controls, and other information on the notification, you can customise them by providing meta data with the Media Session API. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session

Answer (score 1):

When Android is programmed, it gets certain features that allow it to communicate with web hosts and websites. The website will have to be built a certain way that allows it to be communicative, but that seems to be what's happening in this situation.